# Jquery Sorting list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

My Code in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wguan/7yMSz/

The current code allows one to drag and drop between two div boxes. But I was wondering how to auto sort by default so that when i drag between the boxes, both will automatically sort from smallest number on top to largest number at the bottom.

HTML

```
<div id="boxes_holder" class="initBox">
    <div draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-align:center;">1</div>
    <div draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-align:center;">2</div>
    <div draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-align:center;">3</div>
    <div draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-align:center;">4</div>
</div>



<div id="dragBox" class = "initBox">
    <div id="dragBoxTitle" class = "">Box</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxes_holder{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:0px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:#FBFBFB;
list-style-type: none;   
}

#dragBox{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:0px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:#FBFBFB;
list-style-type: none;   
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#boxes_holder, #dragBox').sortable({
    connectWith: '.initBox',


    //Whenever Dropped Item
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).children().length > 4) {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'dragBox') {

                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

My Actual HTML Code with PHP below (doesn't seem to work):

```
<div id = "boxes_holder" class = "initBox">
<?php
//Creates 49 BOXES elements


    $x = 49;
    for($i=1; $i<=$x; $i++){
       echo '<li><span class = "boxes" style="text-align:center;float:left;margin:10px;" > '.$i.'</span></li>';
    }

?>

</div>

<div id="dragBox" class = "initBox">
<div id="dragBoxTitle" class = "">
    Pick Your Numbers:
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer below works fine but when I place it under my code for modification, it doesn't seem to work...please see attached for my newly updated code

Comment: Have updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 5):

Following will sort the elements after the drop.

```
    $('#boxes_holder, #dragBox').sortable({
        connectWith: '.initBox',


        //Whenever Dropped Item
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).find('div.boxes').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo(this);  
            if ($(this).children().length > 5) {
                if ($(this).attr('id') == 'dragBox') {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    function sortAlpha(a,b){  
        return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
    }
```

Check the unfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/7yMSz/1/

Edit : So it need to sorted whenever, the position changed, sorted or dragged/dropped. You need to put it in the `update` event handler.

```
   $('#boxes_holder, #dragBox').sortable({
        connectWith: '.initBox',

        update: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).find('div.boxes').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo(this);  
        },
        //Whenever Dropped Item
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(this).children().length > 4) {
                if ($(this).attr('id') == 'dragBox') {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit 2 : Working with the `<li>` html structure.

```
$('#boxes_holder, #dragBox').sortable({
    connectWith: '.initBox',

    update: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).find('li').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo(this);  
    },
    //Whenever Dropped Item
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).children().length > 4) {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'dragBox') {
                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }
    }
});

function sortAlpha(a,b){  
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
}
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/7yMSz/3/

Comment: The problem with this one is that the original div box is not sorting. So if I don't do any dragging and dropping, and just move the stuff in the initial box, they are not sorting. In other word how can every at everywhere be sorted.

Comment: This works, but not for my case for some reason. For my case I am using PHP to create 49 boxes. From there I sort the boxes but mine doesn't work. I've updated the code...I am not sure if Jfiddle takes php...

Comment: i am pretty sure it has to do with my `.find()` as when I place alert statements before and after, it never prints out the statement after.

Comment: @user1234440 It doesn't work because you are creating `span`s with that class in your php code, instead of `div`s. Try setting the class on the `li` element instead, and finding just by `.boxes`

Comment: in the loop I tried to do :       `echo '<li class = "boxes"><span style="text-align:center;float:left;margin:10px;" > '.$i.'</span></li>';` with your suggestion, but it still doesn't fix it, i also used `.boxes` as oppose to `div.boxes`

Comment: @user1234440 : I have updated the fiddle using the html you given. Please check. http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/7yMSz/3/. You have to use just `find('li')`